# How to Resizing parent Group Item Threejs (Width,Height,Depth)

Tags: three.js

```
let parametricItem: ParametricGroup = new ParametricGroup('Example Group');
let physicalParametricItem: ParametricItem3D = new ParametricItem3D(parametricItem, camera, domElement);

parametricItem.updateAssignmentExpression('width','width_1');
parametricItem.updateAssignmentExpression('height','height_1');
parametricItem.updateAssignmentExpression('depth','depth_1');


let width: NumberVariable | null = parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable('width_1');
gui.add(width, 'value').min(0).max(1000).step(1).name('Wardrobe Width').onChange(updateBoundingBoxUpdate);

let height: NumberVariable | null = parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable('height_1');
gui.add(height, 'value').min(0).max(1000).step(1).name('Wardrobe Height').onChange(updateBoundingBoxUpdate);

let depth: NumberVariable | null = parametricItem.variablesManager.getVariable('depth_1');
gui.add(depth, 'value').min(0).max(1000).step(1).name('Wardrobe depth').onChange(updateBoundingBoxUpdate);
```

i will update width_1,height_1,depth_1 values. it should not be resized based on changes in values.